# docker -v and symlinks

Tags: google-app-engine, dart, docker, boot2docker

I am on a Windows machine trying to create a Dart server. I had success building and image with my files with `ADD` and running the container. However, it is painful to build an image every time I wan't to test my code so I thought it would be better to mount my files with the `-v` command since they are access live from my host machine at runtime.

The problem is that dart's packages folder at `/bin/packages` is really a symlink (if its called symlink in windows) and docker or boot2docker or whatever doesn't seem able to go past it and I get

```
Protocol error, errno = 71
```

I've used dart with GAE and the `gcloud` command somehow created the container, got your files in there and reacted to changes in your host files. I don't know if they used the `-v` option (as I am trying) or they have some auto-builder that created a new image with your files using `ADD` and the ran it, in anycase that seemed to work.

**More Info**

I've been using this Dockerfile that I modified from [google/dart](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/google/dart/)

```
FROM google/dart

RUN ln -s /usr/lib/dart /usr/lib/dart/bin/dart-sdk

WORKDIR /app

# ADD pubspec.* /app/
# RUN pub get
# ADD . /app
# RUN pub get --offline

WORKDIR /app/bin

ENTRYPOINT dart
CMD server.dart
```

As you see, most of it is commented out because instead of `ADD` I'd like to use `-v`. However, you can notice that on this script they do `pub get` twice, and that effectively creates the packages **inside** the container.

Using `-v` it can't reach those packages because they are behind *host symlinks*. However, `pub get` actually takes a while as it install the standard packages plus your added dependencies. It this the only way?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you need to add the Windows folder as shared folder to VirtualBox to be able to mount it using `-v` using `boot2docker`.

`gcloud` doesn't use `-v`, it uses these Dockerfiles https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_docker.
See also https://www.dartlang.org/server/google-cloud-platform/app-engine/setup.html, https://www.dartlang.org/server/google-cloud-platform/app-engine/run.html
`gclould` monitors the source directory for changes and rebuilds the image.

Comment: If you do it right `pub get` is fast because Docker caches it. Do you use boot2docker or not?  Which host OS are you using?

Comment: boot2docker on windows

Comment: my current practice is to delete the image before a new build, I lose the benefits of the cache